# Is there a technical name for the discrete particles seen in a Star Trek transporter/replicator beam?

Tags: star-trek

Looking at this picture, you can see the particles I'm asking about:

[image: View from inside a replicator as Capt. Janeway watches it create a mug of something.]

Comment: That's no particle, that's Chakotay!

Comment: "High-tech wizzbangery"

Comment: Those are "sparkles" according to various scripts. I don't know if that's a technical term though...

Comment: Sometimes, it looks like particles. Sometimes, it looks like a series of circles or lines around whoever or whatever's being beamed. Point is, the effect changes from time to time, and more often than not, it doesn't look like there are any particles involved.

Comment: I'd speculate it's the matter stream emitting something like Cherenkov radiation (a sonic boom for light) when it comes out of the subspace beam.  Per TNG Technical  Manual 9.3. Dispersal. Disengaging the annular confinement
beam will cause the materializing matter stream to have no
reference matrix against which to form. In such a case, the
transport subject will form in a random fashion, usually taking
the form of randomly dissociated gases and microscopic
particulates.

Comment: Reading Rainbow begind the scenes on TNG.  Sparkles at 10min mark. 
 https://youtu.be/uIRz_qpgD-0?si=qOPEh4sTAg93E7BM also I misspoke a bit on tech manual reference.  Dispersion isn't super relevant and it's a mean thing to do to someone - but it's essentially the same process in a proper transport or replicator.

Comment: Looks like Janeway is manifesting her coffee thorough sheer force of will. I sympathise

Comment: Am I the only one confused about why Chakotay is labeled "Krishna" in the image?

Answer (score 4):

The best reference is "[Realm of Fear](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Realm_Of_Fear_(episode))" (S06E02).  It features transporter tech many times and includes inside-out transport views.

Barclay refers to the visible particles as "**phased matter**" within the matter stream.